# Modifying (fixing) an old Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, database-migration

Finding that a relatively recent (but not the most recent) Rails migration was written incorrectly and can't be rolled back

```
remove_column :users, :subscription_id
```

Wants to be

```
remove_column :users, :subscription_id, :integer
```

Now we need to rollback in production and other environments and we can't:

```
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration:

remove_column is only reversible if given a type.
```

How best to handle this? Is it OK to go back and edit 'old' migrations or this going to have unintended negative effects on other users of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project and if there are real use cases for rolling back migrations in the first place.

Your proposed edit won't have any effect on migrating databases forward nor the generated schema.rb. Rolling back a migration is typically done when developing and testing migrations and isn't done on a production environment.

Keep in mind though that although your edit prevents an exception from being raised, you aren't making it truly reversible. Rails can re-add the dropped column but it's not able to populate it with whatever data was in there before it was dropped.